# understanding the parameter "period" in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working with graph api for a while, trying to get some insights for my page.
The page have more than 30 likes. 
I've had a problem that some values for daily insights were not showing, but they are present for the weekly.

So I was trying to understand the weekly insight values.

Example I had page_impressions_unique, which goes as following:

```
  "id": "893613667322766/insights/page_impressions_unique/week",
  "name": "page_impressions_unique",
  "period": "week",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 37,
      "end_time": "2014-07-06T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 38,
      "end_time": "2014-07-07T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 40,
      "end_time": "2014-07-08T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 40,
      "end_time": "2014-07-09T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 58,
      "end_time": "2014-07-10T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 67,
      "end_time": "2014-07-11T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 41,
      "end_time": "2014-07-12T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 33,
      "end_time": "2014-07-13T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 32,
      "end_time": "2014-07-14T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 31,
      "end_time": "2014-07-15T07:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": 31,
      "end_time": "2014-07-16T07:00:00+0000"
    }
  ],
```

Can anyone explain to me the following values? how is it growing before 12 and then the number decreases until 16?
As how some values are not there for daily?

Answer (score 1):

Well I understood the concept of weekly and day28.
The value for weekly is the values of the current day plus the six days before, which makes lots of sense.
Still I couldn't figure out why some daily values are not appearing please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694429/missing-values-from-facebook-insights-for-my-page

Comment: Do you have any idea on what's the difference between `period` and `date_preset`?

I'd appreciate the input.